# Limit image width

Tags: javascript, css, image, tinymce, tinymce-4

When uploading adding high resolution images to a `tinymce` `textarea` they are often exceeding the width of the editor - is there a way to limit the `width` to `100%`

I have tried overriding the `width` of all images on the page using `CSS`, but this doesn't work as tinymce works using a simulated `iframe`, and doesn't use the page's `CSS` rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the tinymce iframe to limit your images in size.

**Using the  tinymce parameter `editor_css` you may define a css file which will be used for the editor content.**

Another way is to set the image width/height using javascript/jQuery:

```
$(tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getBody()).find('img').css('width', '500').css('height', '500');
```